# Does artifactory home directory need to be world-readable?

Tags: artifactory

We operate Artifactory on a RHEL 7 Linux server. It runs as the local user `artifactory`. His home directory is `/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory` and its mode is 755. Our security folks would prefer it to be 750. Does this directory need to be `world-readable` or can we restrict it?

Answer (score 1):

I installed Artifactory and changed the home directory and all its subdirectories to be "chmod 750". After some testing, I did not encounter any issues with this change. I successfully started Artifactory and performed some basic tests such as creating a few repositories, changing some configuration, uploading and downloading artifacts, creating users and permissions, etc. All of my tests were successful and it seems that you can change the mode of the Artifactory home to 750 without any issues.